# Create a drop down from values in a database with PHP in a WordPress page

Tags: php, database, wordpress, drop-down-menu, html-select

I multiple forms on various pages of a WordPress site that all have the same drop down menu.  Rather than update all the values in every select each time they change, I have created a table in my WordPress database that is populated with the source names.  I am attempting to use PHP in the WordPress pages in order to display the drop down, but am encountering issues.  Below is the code I am using for the drop down within the HTML form on the various pages.

```
<?php

echo "<select id=\"source\" style=\"max-width: 165px;\" name=\"source\">";
echo "<option value=\"\">Please select...</option>";
global $wpdb;
$wp_source = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_source;");

foreach($wp_source as $table){
echo "<option value=\"" . $table->name . "\">" . $table->name . "</option>";
}

echo "<option id=\"other\" value=\"other\">Other</option>";
echo "</select>";

?>
```

The table name is wp_source and I am using a Plugin named **Exec-PHP** which allows a user to utilize PHP within WordPress posts/pages/widgets/etc.  What I am seeing in my drop down is the following text:  **name."\">".$table->name."**  Any assistance you might offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try assigning the $table->name to a variable and using the variable

Comment: Hi, @clearshot66

Now I'm getting the following results:

**" . name . "**

Comment: what does `var_dump($wp_source)` give you?

Comment: var_dump($wp_source) gives me a drop down that contains that statement, @BizzyBob

Comment: put it after your last `echo`.  I just want to see what the structure of the `$wp_source` output is.

Comment: No changes and I don't see output, @BizzyBob.

Comment: please post the entire generated output of your `<select>` element

Comment: This is what I get in the developers console:

    <select id="source" style="max-width: 165px;" name="source">
    <!--?php

    echo "<option value=\"\"-->Please select…“;
    global $wpdb;
    $wp_source = $wpdb-&gt;get_results(“SELECT * FROM wp_source;”);
    foreach($wp_source as $table){
    echo “<option value="\&quot;Test\&quot;">” . $table-&gt;name . “</option>“;
    echo var_dump($wp_source);
    }
    ?&gt;<option id="other" value="other">Other</option></select>

Comment: so, your PHP isn't getting executed.

Comment: does your user have the privilege to run `unfiltered_html` ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html

Comment: I am an admin, @BizzyBob.  I should have those rights.

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this using Javascript. Pass your data into the function and create an array called wp_source.

```
list = document.getElementById("source"); 
for (i=0; i < wp_source.length; ++i)
  {
     option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = numbers[i];
     list.add(option);  
  }
```